# Very untyped and recursive class definition that compiles but seems a corner case to me

Tags: f#

These 4 lines compile but do not make sense to me :

```
open System

type mclas (y) =
    member x.m = x.m

let z = mclas (1:>obj)
```

**Question** : In what case would we need to code in such way ? Am I activating subtle class features I am not aware of ?

**Edit** : If there is no use case, what is the status of this piece of code regarding compiler warning/error and is it eligible for some Issue raising on github ?

**Note** : At runtime, the debugger cannot evaluate variable z saying "Function evaluation timed out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member m actually compiles to something like this in IL:

```
.property instance object m {
    .get instance object Program/mclas::get_m()
}
```

So m is a property of type object which has a getter that recurses endless. The C# equivalent of this would be:

```cs
public class mclas
{
    public mclas(object y) { }
    public object x {
        get {
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

Because the recursion never ends, taking too long and/or there is a StackOverflowException happening when the Debugger tries to evaluate m, it cancels and spits out that the evaluation timed out.

And for your actual question: I don't think that you ever need this kind of self-reference in F#, at least I can't think of any possible use.

I think that this behaviour of the compiler makes sense, because a member without paramters will always compile to a get-only property, and then this would be the most obvious way of defining an infinite recursing property (just because this has no use doesn't mean that you can't do it).

Comment: Thanks thegentlecat. For functions, let f x = f x does not compile but let rec f x = f x does thanks to rec keyword. I would have expected the same syntax restriction for classes or at least warnings. By the way, after the let rec f x = f x, if I have let y = f 1, it does not compile, unlike the case let z = ... in my initial question. So the compiler's behaviour does not make sense to me in my class definition case and should reject it or alternatively defines an equivalent of rec keyword for classes or a warning. R: I do not intend to create recursive class types ; it was just an experiment.

Comment: For the question about the "missing" __rec__ keyword, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996035/record-type-recursive-member-functions-and-the-rec-keyword) link. As for the let y = f 1 example, it does not compile because the type inference can not decide which return type the function f should have, thus giving it a generic return type 'b (the function f is 'a -> 'b), and since you can not store an instance of a generic type, it does not compile.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I accept your answer because of the link in your last comment.